# Hojas de estilo css

Tags: css, html5

tengo una duda estaba viendo un video en YouTube y el compa crea una hoja de estilo por cada sección de la pagina mi pregunta es ¿ es bueno, recomendable o de buenas practicas hacer eso ?

ejemplo:
tiene una hoja de estilo para "contactos" otra para "sobre mi" etc.

Comment: Esta pregunta puede quedar cerrada debido a que: *Es probable que esta pregunta sea respondida con opiniones más que con hechos y citas. Debe ser actualizada para que conduzca a respuestas basadas en hechos.*, lee por favor [ask]

Comment: Hay que ver el motivo por la que cada sección tiene su propia hoja de estilos: si a modo de práctica, ejercicio, o probar alguna otra cosa. Pero como estructura de página o sitio, ya no es conveniente linkear tantos stylesheet innecesarios. ADEMAS, TU PREGUNTA ESTA BASADO EN OPINIONES, Y ES POSIBLE QUE SE CIERRE.